# Insert date into MySql Database using JavaFX Datepicker

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I'm trying to insert date to mysql database from data-picker using javaFx.
I am tired by submit this code.

```
@FXML
private DatePicker DPCurrentDate;//fx:id="DPCurrentDate"

// BrandAdded is a Method that i created for insert data into database

private void BrandAdded(){

    DBConnection newCon = new DBConnection();
    con = newCon.geConnection();

    try {
        pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into Brands values(?,?,?,?,?)");
        pst.setString(1, null);
        pst.setString(2, TFBrandName.getText());
        pst.setString(3, TABrandDecription.getText());
        pst.setString(4, lblUserName.getText());
        pst.setDate(5, DPCurrentDate.getValue());
        pst.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddBrandController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

when i run my program it give me this error

```
error: incompatible types: LocalDate cannot be converted to Date
        pst.setDate(5, DPCurrentDate.getValue());
```

Answer (score 4):

You need

```
java.util.Date date = 
    java.util.Date.from(dpCurrentDate.getValue().atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
pst.setDate(5, sqlDate);
```

(using a java.sql.Date).

Comment: how i get the `dpCurrentDate` where i have `DPCurrentDate` as Datapicker.

Comment: I meant the same thing... I was just correcting your variable name so that it matched standard naming conventions :). I had a bunch of other errors in there though (don't know what I was thinking when I put that together...). They are now fixed.

Comment: I'm using this solution in year 2020 with JDK 8. It still works. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.sql.Date;
Date  DPCurrentDate1 =  Date.valueOf(DPCurrentDate);
pst.setDate(5, DPCurrentDate1);
```

This would do  your work

Answer (score 0):

use this in your method `save` or whatever you named it.

```
dateTimePicker.valueProperty().get(),
```

Note. close it with `)` if that is your last item to save.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
pst.setDate(5, ((TextField)DPCurrentDate.getEditor()).getText());
```